# item orientation in wrapgrid in windows8

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8

I use a wrapgrid as the itemspaneltemplate in my app

```
<GridView x:Name="InfoGridView" Margin="50">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="200" ItemHeight="50"  Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Style="{StaticResource AppNameTextStyle}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Width="180"/>
            <Button x:Name="AnotherNameButton"  Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
        </GridView>
```

The TextBlock, TextBox and the Button are display in the middle of the item, how to let them display keep left?

Comment: Try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment=Left` on your `InfoGridView`

Comment: @nemesv thanks for your reply, I have tried it, but still display in the middle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this up on the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within your GridView by adding the following XAML below your ItemsPanel entry.

```
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```